# How do i Get a switch statement with both a int option or char option (scanner included) in java

Tags: java, char, int, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

```
How do i get the user to input a character or number for the choice?
```

What type of scanner do i use or do i create more than one scanner?

Right now the code works with any number but when i input a character i get a syntax error. Any ideas or suggestion would be helpful!!!

```
public class Calc2 {

    private static void Menu(){
        // print introduction
        System.out.println("Calculator");
    }

    private static void Choice(){
        // give 4 different calculations + a way to exit
        System.out.println("\nChoose which type of operation you want to do.");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");
    }

    private static float Addition(){
        //Addition method
        System.out.println("Choose your first number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Choose your second number");
        Scanner  input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = input1.nextFloat();
        float num3 = num1 + num2;
        System.out.printf("%f + %f = %f", num1, num2, num3);
        return num3;


    }
    private static float Subtraction(){
        //Subtraction method
        System.out.println("Choose your first number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Choose your second number");
        Scanner  input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = input1.nextFloat();
        float num3 = num1 - num2;
        System.out.printf("%f - %f = %f", num1, num2, num3);
        return num3;


    }
    private static float Multiplication(){
        // multiplication method
        System.out.println("Choose your first number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Choose your second number");
        Scanner  input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = input1.nextFloat();
        float num3 = num1 * num2;
        System.out.printf("%f X %f = %f", num1, num2, num3);
        return num3;


    }
    private static float Division(){
        // division method
        System.out.println("Choose your first number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Choose your second number");
        Scanner  input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = input1.nextFloat();
        float num3 = num1 / num2;
        System.out.printf("%f / %f = %f", num1, num2, num3);
        return num3;


    }
    private static void Exit(){
        System.out.println("Thank you for using Gaurav's Calculator");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu();
        int input1;
        // call on the menu and choices
        do{

        Choice();
            Scanner operator = new Scanner(System.in);
             input1 = operator.nextInt();


        // get user input for what type of calculation




        // switch case to call on a method based on users choice of calculation

        switch(input1){
        case 1:
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        Addition(); 
            break;
        case 2:
        case 's':
        case 'S':

        Subtraction();  
            break;
        case 3:
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        Multiplication();
            break;
        case 4:
        case 'D':
        case 'd':

        Division(); 
            break;
        case 5:
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            Exit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You chose a wrong number");

        }
    }while ( input1 !=5); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in a character from the `Scanner` and use

```
switch(input1) {
    case '1': case 'a': case 'A': Addition(); break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: do i have to make input1 in a char?

Comment: @user3117328 You don't technically have to (`int` is larger than `char`), but you probably should.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to read in a character (or rather the first char of a string)

```
char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
```

This char can then either be tested in a case such as

```
case '1': case 'a': case 'A'
```

Answer (score -1):

You're problem is that you're reading next input as an int only.
Try doing something like this:

```
     String reply = input.next(Pattern.compile("[1-5aAsSmMdDeE]"));
     int input1;
     try {
         input1 = Integer.parseInt(reply);
     } catch (NumberFormatingException e) {
         input1 = reply.charAt(0);
     }
```

Enjoy.

Comment: One shouldn't use exceptions to implement the logic of an application, if it's possible. That is considered harmful.

Comment: In the OP's case, he does not even need to convert it to an Integer.

Comment: @cdshines I don't agree with that statement. Exception are a valid paradigm for java coding.

Comment: @user2318564, that doesn't mean you should use them to handle the application logic. You shouldn't rely on objects throwing an exception as a part of the flow.